# How to distinguish between “user must change password at next logon” and “wrong password” use cases?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I use UnboundID for the authentication against Active Directory.
I have same error code when I authenticate with the wrong password and when the user is configured with “user must change password at next logon”.
“wrong password” exception:

```
LDAPException(resultCode=49 (invalid credentials), errorMessage='80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece
```

“user must change password at next logon” exception:

```
LDAPException(resultCode=49 (invalid credentials), errorMessage='80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, vece
```

The only difference is the value of word data in the exception message.
I do not want to rely on the message.
How to distinguish between “user must change password at next logon” and “wrong password” use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at this page:

http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors

Shows that:
data 52e = Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid.

data 773 = Entry's password must be changed before logging on LDAP pwdLastSet: value of 0 indicates admin-required password change - MUST_CHANGE_PASSWD

-jim

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1)! 
Do we have any RFC for sub-codes?
Or it is vendor related?
http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/18470.html

Also, how is possible to get the sub-codes in the more conventional way?
I do not want to parse the exception message.

Comment: It is all vendor specific. AFIK, you will have to parse if you want that information. If you find a better way, please advise.